# What is and How to upload Arduino binary files .ino.bin and .ino.elf file on macOS?

Tags: arduino, macos-big-sur, arduino-c++

I'm trying to extract Arduino binary file(ie. hex or bin) from my project.

The project is 100% working without any error, had a test drive and reviewed.
By the contract with my client, I can protect my original source files and my client only needs binary files to upload on their own.
The problem is that I can only use my MacBook currently, and my Windows are on repair.

```
    ~/Documents/Arduino/build  ls -al
total 7592
drwxr-xr-x@  15 songunsuk  staff      480  6 10 22:13 .
drwxr-xr-x@   6 songunsuk  staff      192  6 10 22:13 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 songunsuk  staff     6148  6 10 22:19 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@   1 songunsuk  staff   265168  6 10 22:13 LED_OOP.ino.bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 songunsuk  staff  1843812  6 10 22:13 LED_OOP.ino.elf
-rw-r--r--    1 songunsuk  staff  1740687  6 10 22:13 LED_OOP.ino.map
-rw-r--r--    1 songunsuk  staff     1763  6 10 22:13 build.options.json
drwxr-xr-x@ 147 songunsuk  staff     4704  6 10 22:13 core
-rw-r--r--    1 songunsuk  staff      590  6 10 22:13 includes.cache
drwxr-xr-x@   3 songunsuk  staff       96  6 10 22:13 ld_h
drwxr-xr-x@   2 songunsuk  staff       64  6 10 22:13 libraries
-rw-r--r--    1 songunsuk  staff     9096  6 10 22:13 local.eagle.app.v6.common.ld
-rw-r--r--    1 songunsuk  staff      858  6 10 22:13 local.eagle.flash.ld
drwxr-xr-x@   3 songunsuk  staff       96  6 10 22:13 preproc
drwxr-xr-x@   9 songunsuk  staff      288  6 10 22:13 sketch
```

I guess I extracted binary files successfully and think that `LED_OOP.ino.bin` and `LED_OOP.ino.elf` files are binary files I'm looking for.
But I cannot use and even open the files.

So please let me know How to upload the project with binary files if these files are correct binary files.

Comment: you can turn on verbose output in Arduino IDE and see the upload command

Comment: Those `.bin` and `.elf` files are standard output files from the `avr-gcc` compiler.  Like ~Juraj said, turn on verbose output and see all the commands. All you have to provide the user is the `.hex` file which `avrdude` uploads to the Arduino (I think). Somewhere along the way, `avr-objopy` is used to convert the `bin` (?) to a `hex` file.  On my mac, it's at /Users/zzz/Apps/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply to your valuable comment, and thank you so much everyone!